# Minecraft PE unable to join servers and see marketplace?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So here's my problem, I tried to play on a server with my cousin on MCPE, since we were in different locations we had to make a Microsoft account and add each other on Xbox. After we did that we played on a server for a while and took a rest, when we try and play again, I opened the server tab, but nothing was there, I have 6 servers on that tab, it only said "Coming soon", I opened the Realms tab and it said “Unable to connect to Realms at the moment, try checking your internet”, so then I just restarted my internet, but that did nothing. Can anyone tell me what to do here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your game. If that doesn’t work, log out of your XBox account, restart the app, and log in again. That should fix it if updating didn’t.